# Skew calculation positive when I believe it should be negative. Why is this?

Tags: numpy, scipy, skew

With the following code I get a positive skew regardless of where the majority of counts are, why is this?

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import stats

negativeSkew = np.array([1,1,1,1,1,1,100])
positiveSkew = np.array([100,1,1,1,1,1,1])

print stats.skew(negativeSkew) # 2.04124145232
print stats.skew(positiveSkew) # 2.04124145232
```

Judging from

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Negative_and_positive_skew_diagrams_(English).svg

Shouldn't one be positive and the other negative?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`skew` computes the skew of a set of values, and the order of the values does not matter (similar to how the order of the values passed to `np.mean` and `np.std` does not matter).

Since you passed the same numbers each time, the results are identical.

Here's an example of a simple negative and positive skew:

```
>>> stats.skew([-1, 0, 1, -100])
-1.153777116551257

>>> stats.skew([-1, 0, 1, 100])
1.153777116551257
```

Comment: Thanks for you answer. I see the signs matter. I believe my issue is that I use a histogram of counts which are all positive. If I wanted positive and negative skew I could make the first half of the counts negative and the next half positive. Is there a better way of doing this?

Comment: I don't think I understand what you're asking... but the skew function computes the skew of values, not the skew of a histogram. It's similar to how the more familiar ``mean`` and ``std`` functions compute the mean and standard deviation of values, not of a histogram.

Comment: The sign of the values does not matter: for example, [1, 100, 101, 102] has a negative skew.

Comment: Okay sorry for the confusion. I am definitely trying to compute the skew of a histogram, not of the values. How would I compute the skew of a histogram if this isn't given from the skew of the values?

Comment: This answer might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17588085/kurtosis-skewness-of-a-bar-graph-python